# Ubuntu 16.04 desktop settings missing

Tags: unity, settings

I've just installed ubuntu 16.04 and found out that Gnome shell is default now. I've installed unity shell separately, but there is no context menu on desktop, sidebar and status bar. And I can't change desktop background tpp: there is Appearance item in settings, but background picture changes only for lock screen.